# Unknown web method. Parameter name: methodName in web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am using web services in asp.net with c#. In that I am working in one task that is to call the method from AJAX in web services. But whenever I call the method from AJAX in button click event at that time it shows the error i.e. 500 (internal server error) and when I am go the network in developer tools it shows me

> Unknown web method and method. Parameter name : methodname.

Here is the ajax function code

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "OakscrollWebService.asmx/SendMail",
         dataType: "json",
         data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#mail').val(), subject: $('#subject').val(), message: $('#message').val() }),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d);
         },
         failure: function (data) {
             alert("something went wrong");
             //console.log(msg);
         }
     });
 });
```

And here is the cs code

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public static void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
}
```

I have noticed one more thing that is `sendmail` method is not showing in `asmx` file when I am run that file. Surprised that why it is not coming.

Comment: Before dealing with error, So simply posting to this url sends emails? User must not have direct access to this

Comment: In asmx file also that sendmail method is not displaying

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right. Got IT. Thank You @S.Akbari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.asmx` file, your method should not be `static` if you want to use it across several pages. So just remove the `static` keyword and then it should works fine:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
}
```